# html blog template to wordpress template

Tags: templates, page-template, html

i bought a new template from themeforest and it has a blog template named as blog (the main blog template), blog2 (alternative main blog template) and post which shows the inside of a post. i just checked some online tutorials but it says how to convert a simple html site to wordpress.

but i want to change the the layout, widgets and posts as in my html blog template. can some one explain me how can i convert this html blog to a wordpress template?

Comment: Please always use upper-, lowercase letters, punctuation marks, etc. At least this is no chat. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is a much bigger topic than can be addressed here.

Please take a look at the [WordPress Codex entry on Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Generally speaking, you break the HTML into a header, footer, and content area. The header goes into `header.php`, the footer goes into `footer.php` and the content area goes into `index.php` or another, more specific template file (like `home.php`, `single.php`, `page.php`, etc). You theme use theme functions and some basic `while` loops to output content from the database and onto the page. There's a lot more to it than just that, though (like `styles.css`, `functions.php`, etc).

Again, you *really* need to start by reading [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Sidenote: You can also use the TwentyTwelve theme as reference. TwentyTwelve is included with all new WordPress downloads.